# Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I am trying to send an email message using powershell. That the body of the email will contain the results of the Get-ADuser command I run that is stored in a variable. When I try the code below I get the error "Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported."

Is there something wrong with what I am doing here?

```
$Value = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties propery.. | foreach { $_.propery..}
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Value
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-body` parameter expects a string to be passed to it. You will need to convert your variable to be type string or manipulate its value to be a string. You can accomplish this in numerous ways.

```
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body ($Value | Out-String)
```

`Out-String` works here because it takes your object (`$Value`), which is a **single array object** containing multiple ADUser objects, and converts it into a single string.

See [Out-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string?view=powershell-6) for more details.